# Sharepoint 2013 Active Directory Import - Error NeedsFullImport

Tags: 2013, profile-sync, active-directory-import

I have a Sharepoint 2013 Server in our DMZ (non-Domain joined). We published it to the Internet (with local User Accounts) and now we want to login with our Active Directory Accounts from our Domain.

The best way I found to perform this, is to do an Active Directory Import. I opened the Ports 443, 25, 389, 88 and 53 to our Domain controller (to execute the AD Import).

Now I filled in all needed information and I can see all our AD containers. When I want to continue, the following Error displays: **NeedsFullImport**

[image: NeedsFullImport Error]

My Logfiles shows the following:

> The Execute method of job definition
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ADImport.UserProfileADImportJob
>   (ID 2d42d33c-8eb1-471c-bfc6-4c82e6fd27fb) threw an exception. More
>   information is included below.
>
> NeedsFullImport

I found 2 posts on the Internet, but no one had a solution to this problem. Please guys, help me if you can I'm already really desperate.

Comment: Have you tried to use the LDAPS port 636? Usually you want a secure connection going into DMZ with all of your accounts...

Comment: The User Profile Service has nothing to do with logging onto SharePoint (Authentication or Authorisation).  In order to be able to log onto this farm with credentials from your domain, you'll have to either set up SAML auth via ADFS or if you wish to use Windows Authentication (NTLM or Kerberos), you will need your SharePoint's (non-existant) domain trust the domain who's accounts you wish to log in with.  Keep in mind that your SharePoint environment is in an unsupported configuration as local accounts (and non-domain-joined servers) is not supported for production scenarios.

Comment: Edit:  Forgot Forms-based Auth. which is also a possibility though I've never set it up.

Comment: First of all, thx for the responds. 
@Benny Skogberg: I opened the Port 636 to the Domain Controller as well, but it didn't work out. When I pressed Populate Containers, the Error "The LDAP server is unavailable" showed up. I didn't had the problem with the port 389.

Comment: @Greg W: We already got a Oneway-Trust to our DMZ and opened the ports to the domain controller as well. After I press populate containers, I can cearly see the traffic over this port on the firewall. I think that the trust should be alright, but the error occurs for an other reason. Maybe someone knows why?

Comment: The User Profile Sync in your screenshot is using a domain account in the target domain.  No trust is required here.  You also cannot set up a trust between an AD domain and a server not joined to any domain.  Are we confusing the definition of "non-domain joined" here?  You say you're using local accounts (which may imply that the server is not joined to a domain or are you meaning that the server that SharePoint is on is in a different domain.  To reiterate, the User Profile Service has nothing to do with authentication in this context.

Comment: @Greg W: The Server is in our DMZ and NOT domain joined. At the moment, there are only local user accounts on the server (I needed it to install and configurate Sharepoint 2013). Now I wanna use MySites with our domain Active Directory Accounts. Is there any way I can do this?

The Profile Sync that I posted from the logs comes from the service I startet

Comment: Edit: The Profile Sync that I posted from the logs comes from the service I startet (but this can't work out at the moment, because AD Import isn't configurated yet).

Comment: Profile Sync and AD Import are separate and incompatible import processes.  You have to choose one or the other.  You should be able to sync the profiles without any trusts as the import can run as a domain account in the target domain.  The problem you have is your SharePoint environment has no capability of authenticating anyone from your AD domain.  This could possibly be done with Forms Auth but I've never used it so can't vouch for it.  The other possibility is to authenticate via ADFS in your AD domain, if you have it configured.  As with FBA, I've never done it so I can't help there.

Comment: Edit:  as you note, your SharePoint server is not a member server in a domain so you're in completely unsupported territory as far as MS is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I found these Errors in the Sharepoint Logs, that the databases from Sharepoint needed to be upgraded. 
I found Powershell commands to fix this Problem:

(To be able to upgrade the databases:)

```
PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures
```

(To upgrade all needed Databases:)

```
Get-SPContentDatabase | ?{$_.NeedsUpgrade -eq $true} | Upgrade-SPContentDatabase
```

(One Database woudn't work so I had to upgrade manually:)

```
(Get-SPDatabase | ?{$_.type -eq "Microsoft.SharePoint.BusinessData.SharedService.BdcServiceDatabase"}).Provision()
```

That's it, after this I could create a new data import. I just wanted to share it with you guys, maybe someone of you get the same problem.